# IOS/Objective-C/AVFoundation: Should audioEngine be recreated for every recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

Most of the code samples I've seen for recording audio have code at the beginning to check of the audio engine exists and, if not, to create it.

```
-(void) startRecording {

if (audioEngine == nil) {
        audioEngine = [AVAudioEngine new];
}
```

Then, to stop the audio engine from running, it is common to write:

```
[audioEngine stop];
```

In contrast, for the recognitionTask, many examples put code at the beginning to cancel it and start anew:

```
if (recognitionTask) {
        [recognitionTask cancel];
        recognitionTask = nil;
    }
```

When you stop the engine which evidently frees some resources, are you nonetheless, leaving it allocated?

If all of the elements of speech, the audio engine, the task and the request are used together, it would seem simpler to create them and destroy the all at the same time. My specific question is whether I can do that. I am confused, however,  by why the engine is typically only created if it does not exist, but the other elements are always canceled and then recreated.

Thanks in advance for any insights into why they are treated differently.